# How to call method from component Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

There is a method that is called from template with `e` target:

```
public chooseDocument(e, document: PdfFile): void {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I want to call this method from another, what to pass instead `e`?:

```
public do(): void {
   this.chooseDocument(null, this.document)
}
```

Comment: Minimally `{ preventDefault: () => {} }`, but is there an event triggering `do`? Give a [mre].

Comment: `e` is it `$event` reference from template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to prevent default when calling do(), you can check if e is null before calling in chooseDocument. With something like  `e?.preventDefault();` or `e && e.preventDefault()`.

If you can't modify `chooseDocument()` because it's a part of another liblary, you can try passing in an empty function like `this.chooseDocument({preventDefault: () => }, this.document)`